# How do deactivate flyway:clean goal in profile

Tags: maven-3, flyway

i'm using flyway maven plugin to migrate a database:

```
<build>
[...]
     <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <user>${hibernate.connection.username}</user>
                    <password>${hibernate.connection.password}</password>
                    <driver>${driver}</driver>
                    <url>${url}</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have three environments (dev, pre, pro) and a profile for each. Every environment sets their own properties, so i can use flyway setting concrete profile and make my migrations to DB what i want.

Flyway has a clean goal, this goal allow drops all objects in the schema without dropping the schema itself.

There is some way to desactivate this goal only in one of my profiles? (in prod obviusly :P)

Comment: Could you provide some more info about your build? Which goals do you execute? How do your profiles look? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override call of the flyway plugin in the prod profile using the none phase: http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/howto-disable-inherited-maven-plugin/

Comment: How do you override just the clean goal? In prod mode the migrate goal must work, just the clean goal not.

Comment: It is possible to run clean & migration goals in different executions, just followed one by one in pom.xml.

Comment: I am not following you. Using "none phase" disables all the goals of the (flyway) plugin, not only the clean one. Where is the trick?